# Select separate rows from two tables, order by date

Tags: mysql

I *don't* want to any kind of `JOIN` here. I'm building an RSS feed of two tables using PHP, and I want to select all the rows from the two tables, keeping the rows separate but sorting by a common `created` column.

For example, if I have a table `foo`:

```
id      downloads   views   created
-----------------------------------------------
1       12          23      2011-07-22 00:10:16
2       51          900     2011-07-22 10:11:45
3       8           80      2011-07-23 04:12:18
```

And a table `bar`:

```
id      title       body    created
-----------------------------------------------
1       foo         ogblog  2011-07-21 10:54:07
3       bar         zip     2011-07-24 10:54:07
4       zip         bar     2011-07-25 10:54:07
```

I want to select all data from both tables ordered by the common `created` column, so an example resultset would be (**ignoring `bar.id` as it's not needed**):

```
id      title       body        downloads   views   created             | table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL    bar         zip         NULL        NULL    2011-07-24 10:54:07 | bar
NULL    foo         ogblog      NULL        NULL    2011-07-21 10:54:07 | bar
1       NULL        NULL        12          23      2011-07-22 00:10:16 | foo
2       NULL        NULL        51          900     2011-07-22 10:11:45 | foo
3       NULL        NULL        8           80      2011-07-23 04:12:18 | foo
NULL    zip         bar         NULL        NULL    2011-07-25 10:54:07 | bar
```

**The `table` column isn't needed; I added it to make things a little easier to understand.**

Hopefully it's obvious what I want to do; instead of doing a `JOIN` where a row is generated from columns from two tables, I want to get all the row data with a common column layout where any column that doesn't exist in a table has `NULL` put into it.

Please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: `UNION ALL` sounds like what you need (with dummy columns to account for structural differences)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using dummy columns to account for the different structures, a union to join them and a parent select to handle the ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT foo.id, NULL AS title, NULL AS body, foo.downloads, foo.views, foo.created FROM foo)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT NULL AS id, bar.title, bar.body, NULL AS downloads, NULL AS views, bar.created FROM bar)
) results
ORDER BY created ASC
```

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on @Brendan Bullen's suggestion, here's an example using `UNION ALL` that should work for you:

```
SELECT id as id, NULL as title, NULL as body, downloads as downloads, 
  views as views, created as created, 'foo' as table_name
FROM foo
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as id, title as title, body as body, NULL as downloads, 
  NULL as views, created as created, 'bar' as table_name
FROM bar
ORDER BY created ASC
```

Comment: Got there before me with the actual query! :) Something that always confuses me with the union, does that `ORDER BY` apply to the results as a whole or only the second select statement? i.e. As in my answer, is there any point in separating it out?

Comment: @Brendan, the `ORDER BY` applies to the result of the UNION, so there is no need to use a sub-select.

Comment: Also, I had some typos in my original query. I fixed them now.

Comment: I've used Brendan's answer, but still +1 for being a very helpful person, Ike :-)

Comment: I want to filter both tables on the same data, using something like WHERE foo in (1,2,3). I've added that bit to both SELECTS which works, but is there a way of not having to enter it twice?

Comment: Better answer as for me. Thank you.